# Can I create complex Web Components with Angular Elements

Tags: angular, angular-elements

I have an old application wrote in jquery. There is need new functionality (I want write it in Angular technology), which can be a bit complicated and consist of many components. I wonder if I can use Web Components with Angular Elements. Can it be used as one large and complex component?
Maybe you know a better solution?

Comment: Yes, you can use it. Or you can use vanilla JS https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/customelements#intro

Comment: Please go through this link https://angular.io/guide/elements. So that you will get fair idea how the components are built. for example go though this. https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader